# Webview userAgent not work in react natvie

Tags: react-native, webview, user-agent

```
<WebView source={{html:'...'}} userAgent={DeviceInfo.getUserAgent()}></WebView>
```

I use `WebView` to send a request to a server and set the `userAgent`. But it is found the `user-agent` received by the server is `okhttp/3.6.0`. So what's wrong with the `userAgent`?

Answer (score 0):

You sent data what received in `DeviceInfo.getUserAgent()` , I suggest add your custom data in `userAgent` attribute that you have intended to pass on server.
For example set custom data in WebView, it should work as expected in Android version.

```
 <WebView
      source={ {uri: this.props.url} }
      userAgent="demo-react-native-app"
    />
```

Eventually it won't work with iOS version, here few line code at AppDelegate.m file require for it's support.

```
NSString *newAgent = @"demo-react-native-app";
NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:newAgent, @"UserAgent", nil];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:dictionary];
```

Comment: Even if I add custom data in userAgent, the user-agent got by the server is always 'okhttp/3.6.0'

Comment: @promise06 I get the same problem for Android. It seems `userAgent` prop is not working  -_-. Could you somehow solve the problem?